# Text not filling width of div in Opera Mini

Tags: css, html, width, opera

I am having a problem figuring out why the text is wrapping and not filling the width of the containing div.  This is only happening in Opera Mini on the iPhone and on the Opera Simulator. Opera for ipad and osx display as intended as well as IE, firefox and safari. Any ideas?  Here is the page

[Demo Page](http://innerworkingdesigns.com/demo/demo.htm)

Here is the Opera Mini simulator

[Opera Mini Simulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am sorry this is deemed as too localized.  I don't understand why.  This is a problem with what I believe to be standard and basic css not rendering on the opera mini browser.